# Are those two theories equivalent?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

Lets denote any set that is "the set of all strictly smaller subsets of it" as *size- unreachable*. Formally: $$\operatorname {size-unreachable}(X) \iff \\\forall Y (Y \in X \iff Y \subset X \land |Y|<|X|)$$Now $V_\omega$ qualifies for such a set.

I gave this definition in a prior [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432930/what-examples-of-size-unreachable-sets-in-zfc), where I asked about examples of such sets, the answer given is an $H_\kappa$ set where $|H_\kappa|=\kappa$, (where the $H$ function is defined as: $H_\kappa=\{x:|x|<\kappa\land \forall y\in \operatorname{trcl}(x)\; |y|<\kappa\} $).

My question is about the equivalence of the following two theories:

- ZFC + every set is an element of some size-unreachable $V_\kappa$ stage.
- Extensionality, Separation, and Unreachable Reflection.

**Unreachable Reflection:** if $\phi$ is a formula (*defined terms allowed*) that doesn't use $V_\kappa$, and $\kappa$ is not free, then: $$\phi \implies \exists \kappa : \operatorname {size-unreachable}(V_\kappa) \land V_\kappa \models \phi$$